# Can't submit form and show error message "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: laravel

when I access the form and click the submit button I get an error message.

> Trying to get property 'nama_plg' of non-object

code details

```
<tr>
    <td><b>Nama</b> </td>
    <td>: </td>
    <td>{{ $pelanggan->nama_plg }}</td>
    <input type="hidden" name="pelanggan_id" value="{{ $pelanggan->pelanggan_id }}" required>
</tr>
```

this my controller

```
public function calculate(Request $request)
    {
        $validate = $request->validate([
            'kode_bkg' => 'required|unique:pemesanans',
            'tgl_psn' => 'required',
            'durasi' => 'required',
        ]);

        $data = $request->toArray();
        $pelanggan = Pelanggan::find($request->pelanggan_id);    
        $title = 'Detail Pemesanan';
        $menu = '5';
        
        return view('pemesanan.details', compact('tgl_balik', 'data', 'total_harga', 'bus', 'dp', 'title', 'menu', 'pelanggan'));
    }
```

Route

```
Route::post('pemesanan/details', ['as' => 'pemesanan.calculate', 'uses' => 'PemesananController@calculate'])->middleware('auth');
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: in your function return $pelangaan and see whats inside

Comment: class Pelanggan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['nik', 'nama_plg', 'ttl_plg', 'nmrhp_plg', 'alamat_plg', 'jenkel_plg'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'pelanggan_id';
}

Comment: oh no! thats not what i mean!
read the answer below it wiil help you

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are not validating `pelanggan_id` inside the request body. This might be the cause of `Pelanggan::find($request->pelanggan_id)` can return null. In this case of `$pelanggan` is null, evaluating `$pelanggan->name_plg` will throw exactly the same exception as you get now.

The solution to your problem.

1. Validate `pelanggan_id` field from the request body, so that the controller will return `ValidationException` and stops executing if the `pelanggan_id` field is invalid.
2. Fix `Pelanggan::find($request->pelanggan_id)` into `Pelanggan::findOrFail($request->pelanggan_id)`. It will throw `ModelNotFoundException` in the same case as above.